# building a usage hierarchy in Intellij

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

I want to build a usage graph on a method in Intellij (Java code). For example if I have method A which is called by B and C, then D is calling B, I'm looking for something like 
D->B-> A <-C (in a graph like structure).

I currently do it manually with Alt-F7, pen, and paper. Any tool other than Intellij is also appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate | Call Hierarchy should do what you need.